# unrequire a php file

Tags: php, routes, require

Im working on a website - just learning to improve my coding.
I have a routing system which works like this:

/config/routes.php:

```
$route->add('/' , function() {
    require_once("/application/pages/index.php");
});

$route->add('/register', function() {
    require_once("/application/pages/register.php");
});

$route->add('/login', function() {
    require_once("/application/pages/login.php");
});

$route->add('/logout', function() {
    require_once("/application/pages/logout.php");
});

$route->add('/panel', function() {
   require_once('/application/pages/panel/index.php'); 
});
```

And in my index.php:

```
require_once('application/pages/header.php');

include('config/routes.php');

require_once('application/pages/footer.php');
```

Everything works fine but I need a different header.php and footer.php for when the user goes into the panel. file: /application/pages/panel/index.php

When I require_once a new header file in the panel/index.php then both the new and old header file is loaded. How can I unrequire the header and footer files in the /panel/index.php so I can require different ones? Any suggestions?

Comment: please edit your post and add the exact message you are receiving

Comment: @WEBjuju - sorry, my mistake I meant that both of the header files are loading. I don't know why I wrote that there's and error, probably because Im tired now.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Routing comes from an [MVC design pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm), you should keep your controllers separate from your views.

---

**Templates** and **Views** could be kept separate, also. This meaning our directory set-up can look something like this:

```
- Templates
    - header_one.php
    - footer_one.php
    - header_two.php
    - footer_two.php
- Views
    - index.php
    - someOtherBody.php
```

---

**Here is a simple, but unfinished (that is your challenge) example of an Object that could do what I am explaining:**

```
class Page {
    private $template_path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/templates/';
    private $view_path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/views/';

    protected $header;
    protected $footer;
    protected $body;

    public function setHeader($file_name)
    {
        if(is_readable($this->template_path . $file_name))
        {
            $this->header = $this->template_path . $file_name;
            return $this;
        }
        // add an exception
    }

    /* TODO: */

    public function setFooter() {}
    public function setBody() {}

    /* Render page */

    public function render()
    {
        $page = [$this->header,$this->body,$this->footer];
        foreach($page as $file)
        {
            require_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The idea here is that we can set our page layout, using the above object, within the route method closure, then render / require all the files after the logic.

---

```
$route->add('/', function() {
   $page = new Page();

   $page->setHeader('header_one.php')
        ->setBody('index.php')
        ->setFooter('footer_one.php');

   /* todo: add your logic here */

   $page->render();
});
```

---

Each route can now have its own header, footer and body.
Hope this helped.

Comment: I inserted this class and finished it but I'm getting an error: 

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wampserver\www\cms\application\classes\class_page.php on line 17`

Line 17: `const TEMPLATE_PATH = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/application/templates/';`

Comment: This code snippet is not a **working** version. It is your own responsibility to produce a working version of the concept. Firstly, you will need to change your directory layout, meaning move all your views into a *views directory* and same with your templates. Note: Ensure you `return $this;` to keep the OO flow between the methods.

Comment: You can view more about [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php), following that link.

Comment: I have updated the answer to fix that issue, however. Constants must be strings/integers. They cannot be methods. My bad. Although you could `define('TEMPLATE_PATH' , dirname(__FILE_) . '/template');` and then call it as `TEMPLATE_PATH`

Answer (score 1):

At your place, I will do something like that :

Use out buffer and check if the file is already required. I give you an quick example but adapt the code for you. 
And check the function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php

```
$route->add('/panel', function() {
    include_once('YOUR_SPECIFIC_PATH/header.php');
    require_once('/application/pages/panel/index.php'); 
    include_once('YOUR_SPECIFIC_PATH_header/footer.php');
});
```

And :

```
ob_start();
include_once('config/routes.php');
$mainContent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


include_once('application/pages/header.php');
echo $mainContent;
include_once('application/pages/footer.php');
```

I've not the time for help more sorry but I can explain later if you need

Comment: i'm growing to agree with the php community that believes `ob_` functions usually indicate a design flaw.  this is certainly one of those cases.  for one, it multiplies the necessary lines of code where they can clearly be reduced instead.

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires you to have a `header.php` and `footer.php` in each folder where your sub-controllers (`application/<module name>/index.php`) are.

**index.php**  only call your sub-controllers via routing:

```
// require not include, because "no routing" = "no web site" ;)
require_once('config/routes.php');
```

**application/pages/index.php** include appropriate header/footer w/ relative path

```
require_once('header.php');
// page code
require_once('footer.php');
```

**application/register/index.php** include appropriate header/footer w/ relative path

```
require_once('header.php');
// page code
require_once('footer.php');
```

**etc**

Comment: if your `application/pages/header.php` is the "default" header (and footer), then in any folder/module where you wanted to call that rather than a folder-existant `header.php`, the relative path would likely be `../pages/header.php` so then `require_once('../pages/header.php');`

Answer (score 0):

@KDOT , thanks you for your help but using your code I was getting an error that I could not fix:

```
 Call to a member function setBody() on null
```

but thanks to your code, I managed to rewrite the class my way and now it works ;)
Thanks again @KDOT !

If anyone needs it:

```
class Page {
    private $TEMPLATE_PATH = '/application/templates/';
    private $VIEW_PATH = '/application/views/';

    protected $header;
    protected $footer;
    protected $body;

    public function __construct($header_file, $body_file, $footer_file) {
        $this->header = $this->TEMPLATE_PATH . $header_file;
        $this->body = $this->VIEW_PATH . $body_file;
        $this->footer = $this->TEMPLATE_PATH . $footer_file;
    }

    public function render(){
        $page = [$this->header, $this->body, $this->footer];
        foreach($page as $file) {
            require_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
$route->add('/', function() {
    $page = new Page('header.php', 'home.php', 'footer.php');
    $page->render();
});
```